# the if function in php fo not work with words of the value - if($value = "word")

Tags: php, html

I am trying to create a function in php that if $value = "value" something will be echoed, bu it seems to not working, any idea?

The code:

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
<?php
        include('file.php');
            //Detection values
            $Tablet = "Tablet";
            $Mobile = "Mobile";
            $Computer = "Computer";

        if($Device_Type_GAME === $Tablet){
            echo '
            <h>not supported</h>
            ';
        }elseif($Device_Type_GAME === $Mobile){
            echo '
            <h>not supported</h>
            ';
        }elseif($Device_Type_GAME === $Computer){
            echo '
        <div id="content">
            <iframe width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" src="'.$GameURL.''.$GameURLHash.'"/>
        </div>
        ';
        }else{
            echo '
            <h>can not detect you device!</h>
            ';
            }

?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where is `$Device_Type_GAME` defined? I'm also not familiar with an `h` element in HTML but that's not a PHP issue.

Comment: in the file.php

Comment: What does `var_dump($Device_Type_GAME === $Tablet, $Device_Type_GAME, $Tablet)` give you?

Comment: Also if you are making a function, which this code is not, the variable scope should be considered as well.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that the variable `$Device_Type_GAME` is globally defined at that file .if it's in any function then the you can't get it at this point..
and stop using `echo` for html code, you can just end `<?php ?>` tag and start html in between ur php code and condition as well.
sometimes using `echo` can create a lot of mess.
Thank you.